# PHP-SQL How to get data from a table and separate the records into tables

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a question regarding PHP and phpmyadmin that I can't seem to find the answer for. The thing is that I am working on a website where the user can insert a property, which is then saved in a table called "tbl_property". In this table I am storing things like the id, title, image, as well as price. Now, on the website I have another page where I need to display the properties. For each property that I have in the table tbl_property, I need to do sort of a table. meaning, for property with ID 1, I do a table with an image, title and price, property ID 2 another table with an image, title and price and so on. How can I go around this please?

Comment: there are plenty of tutorials on inserting form data in to a database, you should probably start there. This is far to broad a question for this site.

Comment: I know how to insert into a database, and I know how to view data from a database. What I don't know is how to "split" the records of a table, and store each record in its own table on html.

Comment: You might want to consider having the images of the properties in a separate table as some properties might only have a half dozen images whilst others might have a dozen or more images

Comment: ehm..Start a table with X columns, For each (query result?) is a new row, you fill each cell with the data you want? I don't understand the issue